# First example does not compile due to compiler errors

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, linker, swig

i have problems compiling the first tutorial example of swig for a python wraper due to compiler errors.

I refer to this tutorial http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn4

I created all files and executed the commands as specified in "31.2.3 Hand compiling a dynamic module".

The background: I use swig and gcc in cygwin on a windows 64 bit system.

```
swig -python example.i
gcc -O2 -fPIC -c example.c
gcc -O2 -fPIC -c example_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.7/
```

These commands work fine. 
In the last step, a lot of errors occur. I played with it for at least 2 hours and can not find the error. I have included all relevant python-path as well, but the error persists.

```
gcc -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.so
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `PyArg_ParseTuple'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x4e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32      against undefined symbol `PyArg_ParseTuple'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `PyLong_AsLong'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x79): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `PyLong_AsLong'
...
```

Has somebody an idea where the problem is? I suppose it has something to do with my compiler-settings in gcc in cygwin, but i can not get it to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those are not compiler errors, but *linker* errors. It means it can't find some functions you (directly or indirectly) call. To solve it you need to link with the library that contains those files.

Comment: [This entry](http://www.dabeaz.com/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?SwigFaqDLLUsingCygwin) from the SWIG wiki looks like it might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to the language library, Python in your case. That's where those symbols are defined. You will need something like

```
gcc -shared -L/path/to/python/lib/folder -lpython2.7 ...
```

If the error persists, try

```
gcc -v -shared -L/path/to/python/lib/folder -lpython2.7 ...
```

and see if there is any information in the resulting output that indicates what you might be doing wrong (wrong python library name, etc). If still stuck, copy the output to your question and comment on your update so I can get notified.

Comment: Thanks for the Hint, but the error persists.
The error message does not change.


I have no idea to go on, i cant get rid of this error,
even though i´ve now read a lot about this error. 


I suspect, that is has something to do with the usage of gcc under cygwin, but i am not sure about this. 
I have too little experience with both of them.